# What is the best method to use data in different view controllers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am new to ios development and I am trying to use some methods in different view controllers in regular intervals of time (using same methods in different view controllers).

Can anyone please tell me what is the best method for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using protocol for this. You can never know when you want different method behaviour for different controllers. And you can always implement default behaviour in private category of generic uiviewcontroller.

Comment: Hi Eimantas, I'm actually new to categories, would you mean create a category on UIViewController, that could be overridden in UIViewController subclasses to manage custom behavior? In the mean time, how would you manage this using protocol?

Comment: Answer to first question: yes. Now that i think of it - protocols fit more for defining unifiefd behaviour for completely different classes, so it's better for you to go with category. You define default behaviour in a category and override it in subclasses.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know categories could be used that way (I mean to avoid superclass).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to implement this method in a customViewController that would be subclassed by these viewController and than every viewController would have access to these method.

Alternate way would be to implement it on the appDelegate or on a common tabBarController, navigationController (or whatever) and so every viewController would have access to it.

If the time interval has to be the same for every viewControler, you should do only one time interval and iterate on your viewControllers

Comment: thanks for reply ,what about singleton for this is it really bad idea ?

Comment: I believe you might try to use Eimantas solution, it is a bit of workaround about categories, but this seems to be the nicer way of achieving it.